# creating nice looking URLs

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to make a friendly looking URLs for my ugly URLs.

`mod` directory contains an `index.php` and a `user.php` file. The `index.php` only has some links, of various formats, to the user page.

path to `mod` directory like this : `http://localhost/mod/`

at this time user's urls something like this..

`http://localhost/mod/user.php?id=Ricky etc..`

I need to make that ugly one to nice looking one something like this..

`http://localhost/mod/user/Ricky`

I tried it in my htaccess file, and this is code so far in that file.

```
# Enable Rewriting
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite user URLs
#   Input:  user/NAME/
#   Output: user.php?id=NAME
RewriteRule ^user/([a-z]+)/?$ user.php?id=$1
```

This is not working for me. Hope someone will help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^user/([A-Za-z]+)/?$ user.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

State end of line and case insensitive with [NC,L]

You can also just use \w to match all text chars (non digit)

```
RewriteRule ^user/(\w+)/?$ user.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Here's a cheat sheet for regex:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Comment: what url are you testing on

Comment: I can get this error message - `Oops! This page appears broken. HTTP 404 - File not found.`

Comment: I have some links in my index.html to user.php like this - ` <p><a href="user.php?id=Ricky">Ricky</a></p>`

Comment: thats why i asked what url you are using. The rewrite rule just says user/Ricky so if you are trying mod/user/Ricky it won't work. Also, your written html links won't just magically update. the rewrite rule translates the given URL, but unless it's told to, it won't just redirect old url's to the new format

Comment: when clicking that link (above comment) its going to user.php and it's URLs then like this `http://localhost/mod/user.php?id=Ricky`. I need to changa this URLs.

Comment: change that when you have your rewrite rule working. If the rewrite rule is OK, you can add some 301 redirect rules to update inbound links. You are still advised to update your html to reflect the new url pattern though

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30290/discussion-between-tnk-and-kai-qing)

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^mod/user.php?id=$ mod/user/([a-zA-Z])/$1
```